# TS2339 Typescript error but unsure why... property does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am relatively new to Typescript and am currently building a React app which includes Redux and am using Typescript.

Typescript is giving me the following error in my reducer;

```
ERROR in /Users/<REDACTED>/web/src/redux/reducers/steppedViews.ts
./src/redux/reducers/steppedViews.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/<REDACTED>/web/src/redux/reducers/steppedViews.ts(13,53)
      TS2339: Property 'activeView' does not exist on type '{ activeView: number; } | { totalViews: number; }'.
  Property 'activeView' does not exist on type '{ totalViews: number; }'.

ERROR in /Users/<REDACTED>/web/src/redux/reducers/steppedViews.ts
./src/redux/reducers/steppedViews.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/<REDACTED>/web/src/redux/reducers/steppedViews.ts(15,53)
      TS2339: Property 'totalViews' does not exist on type '{ activeView: number; } | { totalViews: number; }'.
  Property 'totalViews' does not exist on type '{ activeView: number; }'.
```

My action typ definition is as follows

```
export interface SetActiveView {
  type: typeof types.steppedViews.SET_ACTIVE_VIEW;
  payload: {
    activeView: number;
  };
}

export interface SetTotalViews {
  type: typeof types.steppedViews.SET_TOTAL_VIEWS;
  payload: { totalViews: number };
}

export type ReduxActionsSteppedViews = SetActiveView | SetTotalViews;
```

And my reducer is

```
import types from '../types';
import { ReduxActionsSteppedViews } from '../actions/steppedViews';

export interface ReduxStateSteppedView {
  activeView: number;
  totalViews: number;
}
const initialState: ReduxStateSteppedView = { activeView: 0, totalViews: 0 };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action: ReduxActionsSteppedViews): ReduxStateSteppedView => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.steppedViews.SET_ACTIVE_VIEW:
      return { ...state, activeView: action.payload.activeView };
    case types.steppedViews.SET_TOTAL_VIEWS:
      return { ...state, totalViews: action.payload.totalViews };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

I am confused as to why this is happening because from my understanding, the type defined is '{activeView: number;} | {totalViews: number;}' so it should be able to see either *.activeView or *.totalViews.

Any guidance on this error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declared type is `{activeView: number;} | {totalViews: number;}`, so neither activeView or totalViews are required property in `ReduxActionsSteppedViews.payload`

Typescript does not know if you have done type checked (in your case), so you need to tell her:

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action: ReduxActionsSteppedViews): ReduxStateSteppedView => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.steppedViews.SET_ACTIVE_VIEW:
      return { ...state, activeView: (<SetActiveView> action).payload.activeView };
    case types.steppedViews.SET_TOTAL_VIEWS:
      return { ...state, totalViews:(< SetTotalViews> action).payload.totalViews };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That has of course done the trick but doesn't feel very neat. Is there a way I can change my code to make this a little neater? I followed the react-redux guide to using it in typescript to arrive at the merged type definition for actions. Or is this solution acceptable?

Comment: If you don't like to create only one interface that merges two interfaces with `?` and ` |` operators, I think this is the only approach. :)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956678/conditional-data-types-on-union-data-types , this post might help you understand conditional typing