# Conditional data types on union data types

Tags: typescript, union-types, conditional-types

Assume that you have the following types:

```js
type Foo = {
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: null
}

type Bar = {
    prop1: 'bar',
    prop2: number
}

type FooOrBar = Foo | Bar
```

Is it possible to rewrite the above code using conditional types?

I have tried the following:

```js
type FooOrBar = {
    prop1: 'foo' | 'bar'
    prop2: FooOrBar['prop1'] extends 'foo' ? null : number
}
```

But when trying to declare a var like so:

```js
const sample1: FooOrBar = {
    prop1: 'foo',
    prop2: null
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

It seems that `FooOrBar['prop1'] extends 'foo'` is always `false` which shouldn't be since `FooOrBar['prop1']` is a union type of `'foo' | 'bar'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the reason not to use union types?

Comment: @KarolMajewski No reason! the question is just out of curiosity :)

Comment: @KarolMajewski Do you believe that `FooOrBar['prop1'] extends 'foo'` being never `true` is a Typescript limitation or a mistake from my side?

Comment: The compiler is right there. It works like this: `FooOrBar['prop1']` is _always_ `'foo' | 'bar'` because you are referencing the `FooOrBar` type you have just defined, not a particular instance of that type. And because `'foo' | 'bar'` does not extend `'foo'` (because a union is wider than its single members, not narrower), the false branch is used by the conditional type every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that, but you'd still need to provide the type argument explicitly.

```
type FooOrBar<T extends 'foo' | 'bar'> = {
  prop1: T;
  prop2: T extends 'foo' ? null : number;
}

const test: FooOrBar<'foo'> = {
  prop1: 'foo',
  prop2: null,
}
```